# Get indices that satisfy some criteria

Tags: python, pandas

In Pandas, how can I get a list of indices of a series/dataframe for the entries that satisfy some property?

The following returns a `Series` object

```
my_dataframe.loc[:,'some_column'] == 'some_value'
```

that looks like this:

```
519     True
509    False
826    False
503    False
511    False
512    False
500    False
507    False
516     True
504    False
521    False
510    False
351    False
522    False
526    False
517    False
501    False
```

but what I want is two lists, one with

```
[519, 516]
```

and one with the rest of indices. How can I do this in Pandas?

Comment: itertools.filter(lambda x: x[1] , (my_dataframe.loc[:,'somecolumn'] == 'some_value') )

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
In [8]: df = DataFrame(randn(10,2),columns=list('AB'))

In [9]: df
Out[9]: 
          A         B
0 -1.046978  1.561624
1 -0.264645  0.717171
2  0.112354 -2.084449
3 -1.243482 -1.183749
4  1.055667  0.532444
5 -1.295805  2.168225
6 -1.239725  0.969934
7 -0.354017  1.434943
8 -0.867560  0.810315
9  0.097698 -0.033039

In [10]: df.loc[:,'B'] > 0
Out[10]: 
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
6     True
7     True
8     True
9    False
Name: B, dtype: bool

In [14]: x = df.loc[:,'B'] > 0

Per Tom/Andy, much simpler 

In [33]: x[x].index
Out[33]: Int64Index([0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], dtype=int64)

In [34]: x[~x].index
Out[34]: Int64Index([2, 3, 9], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Heh, you edited after I posted.  Any reason you're using `.nonzero()` instead of a boolean slice on the index?

Comment: the `x[x] ` part is kind of amazing... mind explain a bit why this works?

Answer (score 5):

A slight variant on @Jeff's example:

```
In [18]: df
Out[18]: 
          A         B
0  0.319489  1.012319
1  0.494205 -0.918240
2  1.501922 -0.409661
3 -1.593702  0.705407
4 -0.735312  1.037567
5 -0.201132 -0.673124
6  1.237310 -0.877043
7 -0.946714  0.984164
8 -0.923548  0.415094
9  0.135281 -0.199951

In [14]  list1 =  df.index[df.loc[:, 'B'] > 0]

In [15]: list1
Out[15]: Int64Index([0, 3, 4, 7, 8], dtype=int64)

In [16]: list2 = df.index - list1

In [17]: list2
Out[17]: Int64Index([1, 2, 5, 6, 9], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: How do you get `list1`? All I have is `my_dataframe.loc[:,'some_column'] == 'some_value'` as in the OP. Thanks,

Comment: @user815423426 doh sorry.  Missed that when copy pasting.  Fixed now.  You still do == some_value,  the important part is that its the index you're slicing into.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Jeff's example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,2),columns=list('AB'))
```

[image]

*You can use `query` instead of a lot of nested brackets:*

```
df.query('B>0.5').index.tolist()    # it prints [0, 7, 8, 9]
```